# Date difference, in Business Days/Hours/Mins?

Tags: perl

Hoping for some help figuring this out. I need to calculate the business days/hours/mins between 2 dates. I'm currently using Date::Manip for this but it seems to only be giving me the days, but not the hours and minutes.

Here's a snippet of what I've got:

```
use Date::Manip;
Date_Init('WorkDayBeg = 09:00', 'WorkDayEnd = 17:00');
..
my $today_date = &ParseDate("today");
my $parsedStart = &ParseDate("2012-01-26 13:32:49.000");
..
my $err;
my $delta = DateCalc(ParseDate($parsedStart),$today_date,\$err,3);
..
print "Raw Delta: $delta\n";
$delta = Delta_Format($delta,2,'%st');
print "Formated Delta: $delta\n";
```

Today is 2012-01-26. When I run the script, the result is:

```
Raw Delta: +0:0:+0:0:0:0:0
Formated Delta: 0.00
```

...As another example, if $parsedStart is 2011-11-22 18:50:24.000, I get:

```
Raw Delta: +0:0:+0:+46:0:0:0
Formated Delta: 3974400.00
```

What am I missing to also get the hours and minutes?

Thank you.

Comment: Works nice for me (version 6.30). What version are you using?

Comment: Works for me, too with both 6.30 and 5.56.  A difference I did notice is in 5.56 `today` means "now" and `yesterday` means "24 hours ago".  In 6.30 `today` means "midnight on this date" and `yesterday` means "midnight on the previous date".  This may be confusing things for you.

Comment: I'm using 6.25 (company regulated version). When you folks say it works for you, do you mean that you're getting the hours and minutes returned and not just days like I'm getting?

Comment: @Schwern,
Thanks for you comment, that led me to trying "now" instead of "today" for the $today_date and that finally switched the mode into returning the hours/minutes/seconds that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is an implementation difference between 5.x and 6.x of Date::Manip, where `today` (and `yesterday`) have different meanings between the versions.

To get the desired behaviour under 6.x, use `now`.